# get appended div id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way I can get the id (or any other reference to) the element I've just appended using jQuery `.append()` ?

I'm receiving an html string with ajax and injecting in a div.

```
$.get(URL, args).success(function (response) {

$('#mainDiv').append(response);

});
```

Now I have to change something to the newly appended div (like a css property).

**Please note!** These solutions are not accepted, reasons are provided.

- append to a temporary unique div - reason: the response contains javascript which works only if the injected html is in its environment. Calling .append will make this js run and it must be inside of mainDiv.
- using a known id for the injected div - reason: the div I'm receiving in response has an id but it could be a random string and, for the moment, I need to assume I don't know it.

Perhaps anybody know a secure, reliable and consistent way to access the node I've just created in mainDiv. If .append always attach at the end, perhaps refering last node is ok: am I wrong?

Comment: try something like 
alert($(response).attr("id"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have jQuery object reference like: `var j =$(response);` , and then append it : `$('#mainDiv').append(j);` and change its css: `j.css("border":"0");`

Comment: cool idea, let me try. If response contains javascript will it get executed when I reference it or just when I append? I'm trying it now.

Comment: @Saturnix try it and let us know! :)

Comment: hell yeah! It is working! I totally ignored the possibility to reference jq nodes like this. Awesome! I'll mark as correct when possible, thanks a lot for your solution.